# Configuring servlet url-patterns without web.xml

Tags: java, spring, servlets, web

I know this can be done in servlet 3.0 with the @Webservlet annotation where you just assign the url-patterns and not have to do any configurations within a web.xml. Is there a way to programmatically assign a servlets url-pattern for applications running servlet 2.5?

I am creating a library which multiple applications will depend on and trying to make it so each of these applications do not have to explicitly configure any servlet url mappings for the servlets in the library I am creating within their respective web.xml file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `web.xml` and `@Webservlet` are both mechanisms for the *server* to know where to route requests by examining the war, you would have to be able to manipulate the *server* if you wanted to do it in code. This is at least theoretically possible, since the server could offer for example a JMX endpoint for configuration or you could go directly into the [innards of the server](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2015/02/05/programmatic-equivalents-of-web-xml-sections-for-tomcat/).

However while it might be possible, it would be a non-standard way and you would have to write different tricks for all the servers you want to support. That's not something you *want* to do.

Finally, if you're creating a library, why does it have servlets in it? It shouldn't be the responsibility of the library to create servlets or decide which urls they're assigned to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, guess a few configurations in the applications web.xml is mandatory for servlet 2.5 then.The library will only have one servlet responsible for implementing healthchecks to applications that depend on it. Guess library is not the correct terminology, more of just a project dependency that adds more functionality to applications that use it. We want this process of implementing healthchecks to be the same across all applications and for the url-patterns to be the same across the board.